# Always getting the same image in while loop

Tags: html, css, perl, cgi

I am making a post where you can put comments, and if the post seems to have a photo attached, there's a link where you can click and a CSS popup window will appear with the image as its content.

However, when getting data from the database, I always get the same image – why is that?

Here's my code:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_owner IN ($name1) ORDER BY post_id DESC";
$queryhandle=$connect->prepare($query);
$queryhandle->execute();
while(my $c=$queryhandle->fetchrow_hashref()){
    if("$user_id" eq "$c->{post_owner}"){
        $magic_button="<a href=\"delete.pl?p_id=$c->{post_id}\" target=\"_blank\"><button id=\"button_1\">Remove</button></a>";
    }else{
        $magic_button="";
    }
    HTML::Entities::encode($c->{post});
    HTML::Entities::encode($c->{post_attach});
    our $post_name="$c->{post_owner}";
    my $check_attach=length("$c->{post_attach}");
    if($check_attach==0){
        our $img_src="";
    }else{
        our $img_src="<img src=\"$mhost/$c->{post_attach}\" style=\"border-bottom-right-radius: 2pt;border-bottom-left-radius: 2pt;border-top-right-radius: 2pt;border-top-left-radius: 2pt;\"/>";
    }
print <<HTML;
<table id="post"><td>
<a href="profile.pl?username=$post_name" style="TEXT-DECORATION:none;color:none;"><img src="$mhost/$c->{post_image}" width="50" height="50" id="image-style"/> <font face="arial" size="4" color="black"><b>$post_name</b></font></a><br />
<p style="word-spacing:3px;">
$c->{post}<br />
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>IMAGE</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="content">
            $img_src
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</p>
```

Every time I click the "Let me pop up" link, I get the same image from the recent post or newest post that has a photo attached.

Comment: `if("$user_id" eq "$c->{post_owner}")` would be much better without quotes. You can use `qq()`  instead of `""` quoting (no need for escaping `\"`). Also you could benefit from `use strict;use warnings;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem:

```
id="popup1"
```

`id` never changes between iterations, so the first one is used (I can't see any `javascript` here, so it's a guess, I'm not quite sure how it works exactly).

Also this code is horrifying in many ways, let me know if you want suggests for other improvements.